# Getting callback URL mismatch in an Angular 2 application

Tags: redirect, angular, authentication, auth0

I use Auth0 to authorize users via Google, Facebook and others. This works perfectly if you click log in while the URL is on the list of white-listed callback URLs in Auth0.

But my web application can have any number of different URLs, so having a simple white-list with some allowed URLs does not work.

The login always tries to redirect back to the same URL as I logged in from, and this URL is most of the time not in the list of allowed URLs.

I have tried all kinds of variations of the above settings, but I only get errors like these ones:

> The url "https://x.com/posts/gif/hot/1" is not in the list of allowed callback URLs
>   The url "https://x.com/posts/world/new/1" is not in the list of allowed callback URLs
>   The url "https://x.com/posts/nature/hot/6" is not in the list of allowed callback URLs
>   The url "https://x.com/posts/gaming/hot/3" is not in the list of allowed callback URLs

The Lock configuration related code:

```
options = {
    auth: {
        callbackURL: 'https://x.com',
        // redirectUrl: 'https://x.com',
        responseType: 'token',
        // sso: true,
        // redirect: true,
        params: {
            scope: 'openid user_id name nickname email picture'
        }
    }
};

// Configure Auth0
lock = new Auth0Lock('x', 'x.auth0.com', this.options);

constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

    // Add callback for the Lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

        // Fetch profile information
        this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The login method:

```
public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show({
        callbackUrl: 'https://x.com',
        state: this._router.url
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the latest version of Lock ([Lock 10](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization)) and if that's the case there are a few issues with the code you included:

- The [URL to which Auth0 will redirect to](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#redirecturl-string-) after the user completes the authentication step is specified through `auth: { redirectUrl: '...' }` and you have that line commented and instead the code is incorrectly using `callbackURL`.
- [According to the docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/migration-guide#customizing-options), the `show` method no longer takes any arguments.
- Independently of the Lock version the [`state` parameter](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state) should be used to mitigate CSRF attacks so using it exclusively to pass contextual information may be insecure.

---

Given you have the `redirectUrl` commented you probably also gave it a try; did you got the same behavior when using that parameter?

Based on the documentation the required configuration for what you're trying to achieve should be accomplished by having:

```
options = {
    auth: {
        redirectUrl: 'https://example.com/login/callback',
        responseType: 'token',
        params: {
            state: '[your_state_value]',
            scope: 'openid user_id name nickname email picture'
        }
    }
};
```

```
public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
};
```